# Combining two for else block

Tags: python

I have two for else block which verifies two integers,Is it possible to combine both together?

```
                    for vars in result['events']:
                        if vars['yyy'] == 977:
                            break
                    else:
                        raise AssertionError('output not found')
                    for vars in result['events']:
                        if vars['yyy'] == int(line.split(',')[-1], 16):
                            break
                    else:
                        raise AssertionError('output not found')
```

Comment: Use `or` in your `if` like: `vars['yyy'] == 977 or vars['yyy'] == int(line.split(',')[-1], 16)`.

Comment: @d_kennetz: `else` legally combines with `for` in Python; the `else` block is executed when the `for` runs to completion without `break`ing, raising an exception or `return`ing. It's typically used for needle in a haystack searches; you `break` if you find the needle, and if you never find the needle, the `else` block executes to tell you so.

Comment: Side-note: If `line` is never changing in the loop, you want to perform the `int(line.split(',')[-1], 16)` outside the loop and store it; otherwise you'll repeatedly re-`split`, re-index, and reparse as `int` for every value looped over.

Comment: By "combine" do you mean the `else` only executes if neither is found, or the `else` executes when one is missing? Basically, if there is a `977` value, but not a `int(line.split(',')[-1], 16)` value, should the `else` block run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers assume you want to find one of two needles in a single haystack, and don't care which one you find, but the question isn't clear if that's the correct solution.

To cover the case where you need *both* search values to be found (looking for two different needles in one haystack, and both must exist), there is no easy syntax to do it. But you can build that logic out of a `set` and `for`/`else`:

```
 remaining = {977, int(line.split(',')[-1], 16)}

 for vars in result['events']:
     remaining.discard(vars['yyy'])
     if not remaining:
         break
 else:
     raise AssertionError('Expected outputs not found: {}'.format(remaining))
```

`remaining.discard(vars['yyy'])` removes each `vars['yyy']` if it exists, and silently ignores it if it does not. When both expected values have been seen (and discarded), the `set` is empty, and you `break`, bypassing the `else`. If one or more values has not been seen, they'll remain in `remaining` and can be incorporated into the error message.

Answer (score 3):

With simple `or` condition:

```
for vars in result['events']:
    if vars['yyy'] == 977 or vars['yyy'] == int(line.split(',')[-1], 16):
        break
else:
    raise AssertionError('output not found')
```

---

*Update* after condition clarification:

(also `line.split(',')[-1]` is replaced with `line[line.rfind(',') + 1:]`)

```
yyy_set = {977, int(line[line.rfind(',') + 1:], 16)}

for vars in result['events']:
    vars['yyy'] in yyy_set and yyy_set.remove(vars['yyy'])
    if not yyy_set: break   # all set items were consumed
else:
    raise AssertionError('output not found')
```

Comment: the `else` block should be indented to be inline with the `if`.

Comment: @RobertStiffler, no it's `else` to `for`.

Comment: I guess some people just missed that convenient Python `for/else` feature

Comment: @RobertStiffler: `for`/`else` combine for needle in haystack searches. If you find the needle, you `break`, and the `else` is skipped; if you never `break` (or otherwise force an early exit, e.g. by throwing an exception or returning), the `else` is executed to handle the "needle not found" case.

Comment: [for/else](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/for_-_else.html#else-clause)

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest @Austin @ShadowRanger I was not aware of `for/else`. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I need to check both the if conditions in for loops

Comment: @rr007, see my update for your clarification

Answer (score 0):

The question could have a bit clearer that what it is. Based on what I could understand, you are looking for 2 different values in result['events']. You could use 'or' condition to club the 2 conditions together.

```py
if foobar == 'bac' or zoo == '123':
     blah
else: 
     bleh
```